# Scrollable div with absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that is positioned as `absolute`. This `div` will follow the user when they scroll down the page. The `div` contains dates next to each other. Another `div` is below it that contains data relative to the one above it. It sorta looks like this. Both of these are contained inside a `div.`

```
1/1/1901 | 1/2/1901 | 1/3/1901 | ...
Blah     | Blah     | Blah     | ...
```

As you see, the dates and info will continue throughout the `div`. Extending outside of the parent `div`.

The `div` that contains both of the inner `divs` is scroll-able horizontally, my problem is that the `div` that is positioned as `absolute` should also scroll at the same time the `div` that is not positioned as `absolute`. It just stays static.

Is there a way to make the `div` positioned as `absolute` be able to scroll horizontally to see the other dates on it that are outside of view?

**EDIT**

I just tried to add `position: fixed` and that didn't make it scroll-able either.

Comment: I think you want fixed not absolute.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.  Please post the HTML and CSS you have so that we can help out and provide a solution to the question.

Comment: `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll` will allow scrolling of a div. *Be aware that the div must have a set `height` or `max-height`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This (Might want to click full page to fully see it):

```css
body{margin:0}
div{height:100vh;width:100vw}
div.page1{background-color: red;}
div.page2{background-color: blue;}
div.page3{background-color: green;}
div.page4{background-color: yellow;}
div.floating{width:20vw;position:fixed;top:5vh;background-color: white;height:5vh;right:0;overflow-x:scroll;white-space:nowrap;line-height:4vh;overflow-y:hidden}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page1"> </div>
<div class="page2"> </div>
<div class="page3"> </div>
<div class="page4"> </div>
  <div class="floating"> 
 Blah     | Blah     | Blah     |Blah     | Blah     | Blah     |Blah     | Blah     | Blah     |Blah     | Blah     | Blah     |
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eebjqmdx/

All your follow content will go in div.floating

EDIT: Updated Fiddle See this fiddle for the linked scrollbars: https://jsfiddle.net/eebjqmdx/3/ (I think this is what you wanted)

Comment: This is somewhat like I want. Is there a way to map the scroll bars to scroll at the same time? and hide the one that is floating?

Comment: So as you scroll down on the page, the div should scroll horizontally?

Comment: Map both the horizontal scroll bars. So scrolling on one would scroll on the other